# Neo4j Syntax Exception while creating an apoc procedure inside a apoc trigger

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I am creating an apoc procedure inside a apoc trigger. The error in the logs says this

"
org.neo4j.exceptions.SyntaxException: Variable `node` not defined (line 1, column 26 (offset: 25))
"MATCH(p1:SPerson { name: node.name}) CREATE (p1)-[:Enrolled]->(c)"

"

My apoc trigger code

```
 CALL apoc.trigger.add('loadEnrollments',   
"UNWIND apoc.trigger.nodesByLabel($assignedLabels, 'Enrollment') AS node
 MERGE (p1:SPerson { name: node.name, cell: node.cell, created_at: node.created_at})
 WITH p1, node
 MATCH (c:Course {name: 'Paradigm Shifting 101'})
 MATCH (n:SPerson)
 WITH p1, node, COUNT(n) as size
 CALL apoc.do.when(
 size>3,'MERGE (p1)-[:Waitlist]->(c)',
 'MATCH(p1:SPerson { name: node.name}) CREATE (p1)-[:Enrolled]->(c)') YIELD value
 DETACH DELETE node", 
 { phase: 'after' });
```

Answer (score 0):

With respect to your immediate question, you need to pass `node` to `apoc.do.when` so that its internal query can access it.

However, in actuality, you should change your query so that the internal query does not even need to do a `MATCH`:

```
CALL apoc.trigger.add(
  'loadEnrollments',   
  "UNWIND apoc.trigger.nodesByLabel($assignedLabels, 'Enrollment') AS node
   MERGE (p1:SPerson { name: node.name, cell: node.cell, created_at: node.created_at})
   WITH p1, node
   MATCH (c:Course {name: 'Paradigm Shifting 101'})
   MATCH (n:SPerson)
   WITH p1, c, node, COUNT(n) as size
   CALL apoc.do.when(
     size>3,
     'MERGE (p1)-[:Waitlist]->(c)',
     'MERGE (p1)-[:Enrolled]->(c)',
     {p1: p1, c: c}
   ) YIELD value
   DETACH DELETE node", 
   { phase: 'after' }
);
```

Comment: Thank you!. That worked. Also, you suggested 'that the internal query does not even need to do a match'. Is that a standard practice?

Comment: Generally, you should avoid re-performing a query for a node once you already have that node.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense.Can you also please suggest me something on the following question. 

Your expertise is greatly appreciated.


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62943204/neo4j-questions-on-syntax-apoc-trigger