# Neo4j- questions on Syntax apoc trigger

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I have the following APOC trigger which contains a apoc procedure. This works as desired but I am wondering if I used a lot of WITH statements, is that the way to go? or is there a better way to refactor this code. I am still new to neo4j so not sure.

The control flow- Whenever the Enrollment node is created, it creates an SPerson node and depending on the size(number of SPerson nodes) it creates an enrolled or waitlist(if size>3, and deletes enrolled relation) relation with the course node.

```
CALL apoc.trigger.add('loadEnrollments',   
"UNWIND apoc.trigger.nodesByLabel($assignedLabels, 'Enrollment') AS node
 MERGE (p1:SPerson { name: node.name, cell: node.cell, created_at: node.created_at})
 WITH p1, node
 MATCH (c:Course {name: 'Paradigm Shifting 101'})
 WITH node
 MATCH (n:SPerson)
 WITH node, COUNT(n) as size
 CALL apoc.do.when(
 size>3,
 'MATCH(p1:SPerson),(c:Course) 
 WHERE p1.name=node.name
 CREATE (p1)-[:Waitlist]->(c)
 WITH p1,c 
 MATCH (e:Enrollment) DETACH DELETE e',
 'MATCH(p1:SPerson),(c:Course) 
 WHERE p1.name=node.name
 CREATE (p1)-[:Enrolled]->(c)
 WITH p1,c 
 MATCH (e:Enrollment) DETACH DELETE e', {node:node}) YIELD value
 DETACH DELETE node", 
 
 { phase: 'after' });
```

Comment: You have a lot of issues.  For example, the 2 ` MATCH (e:Enrollment) DETACH DELETE e' clauses seem wrong. It would delete *all* `Enrollment` nodes.

Comment: Yes that was my purpose. I don't want any 'enrollment' nodes in neo4j at the end. They are only here for starting the trigger. The nodes that have a purpose are the 'SPerson' nodes which will have properties(created from the enrollment nodes and enrollment nodes will then get deleted) and relations with the course node.
\n

EXAMPLE 
CREATE (:Enrollment { name: "Manish", cell: "6462265667", created_at: TIMESTAMP()});






#This will start the trigger and create a 'SPerson' node with a 'enrolled' relationship with the 'course' node.

Answer (score 0):

You should:

- minimize the number of rows of data that have to be processed for a query, and
- not repeat operations unnecessarily.

With those rules in mind, this query may work (efficiently) for you:

```
CALL apoc.trigger.add(
  'loadEnrollments',
  "
  CALL apoc.cypher.doIt('MATCH (e:Enrollment) DETACH DELETE e', {}) YIELD value
  WITH value
  MATCH (n:SPerson)
  WITH COUNT(n) as size
  MATCH (c:Course {name: 'Paradigm Shifting 101'})
  UNWIND apoc.trigger.nodesByLabel($assignedLabels, 'Enrollment') AS node
  MERGE (p1:SPerson {name: node.name, cell: node.cell, created_at: node.created_at})
  DETACH DELETE node
  CALL apoc.create.relationship(p1, CASE WHEN size > 3 THEN 'Waitlist' ELSE 'Enrolled' END, {}, c) YIELD rel
  ",
  { phase: 'after' }
);
```